# How to change password ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using putty to connect to a database server, but my current password is too complicated and I want to change this.

How make this putty terminal after I'm logged in with current credentials?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Type "passwd" (without quotes)

System prompt you to type your new pass, and then to confirm it.